# Xamarin Forms - Convert Image to Bitmap without using Native (iOS/Android) code

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.forms

Is there are way that you can convert Xamarin Forms images to bitmap format (for storing in an SQLite database) without having to write the code twice for iOS and Android individually?

Comment: What is the original source of the "Image"?

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries available for image loading and conversion.

- You could use [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat), a simple light weight library for cross platform image loading and conversion.
- You could use [DevKit.Xamarin.ImageKit](https://github.com/humbertojaimes/DevKit.Xamarin.ImageKit) it's a light weight library it has implementation for each platforms
  like for Android it will return `Bitmap`, for iOS it will return `UIImage` from `byte[]` and for `UWP` it returns a `WriteableBitmap` from `byte[]`
- Or, more sophisticated library like [Fast & Furious Image Loading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) It supports built in caching and transformation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it appears that Fast and Furious has transformation in terms of vector transforms, but not data type, is this correct?